# how to send file along with data in formdata in angular 10

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, angular-forms, angular10

i want to send data in FormData along side with Files in the same object.

i have an object

```
var dataForm : FormData = new FormData();
var objectToSend : any = {};
objectToSend.object1 = {
   Name:'Name',
   ID: 1
};
objectToSend.Arr = [1,2,3];
```

i 've found out how to put a file in the FromData

```
this.dataForm.append('file', <File>files[0], (<File>files[0]).name);
```

but when putting the data object in it the same way i put the file like this ...

```
var stringfiedObejct = JSON.stringify(objectToSend);
this.dataForm.append('data', new Blob([stringfiedObejct], { type: 'application/json' }));
```

and the call like

```
this.Http.post(`apiPath`, this.dataForm, { reportProgress: true, observe: 'events' })
      .subscribe(event => {
        

      });
```

it generate error **415 Unsupported Media** although the api method has the same definition for the object

```
public class DataObject
{
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class RequestParams
{
     public List<int> Arr {get;set;}
     public DataObject object1 {get;set;}
}
```

and the api is ...

```
[HttpPost("uploadFile"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public IActionResult Upload(RequestParams param)
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            return Ok();
        }
```

although the file is received in the api, but as soon i put the object in the FormData it generate that error

Comment: Were you able to find solution to your problem? I see some threads that suggest that I am suppose to delete Content-Type from headers. However, i have been unsuccessful so far

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass object in formdata,you can do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820123/asp-net-core-nested-iformfile-list-is-always-null):

DemoModel:

```
public class DemoModel
{
   public IList<IFormFile> Images{ get; set; }

   public DataObject object1 {get;set;}
}
```

pass object to FormData:

```
var pdata = new FormData();
            pdata.append('object1.Name', 'Name');
            pdata.append('object1.ID', 1);
```